# Retrieving data by id then rendering that ids information React, MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs

Be gentle, I am a very very new newb!

I am trying to show only the data of a single item. My function in the backend for retrieval from MySQL does what it should (shows all the data for a single ID). I am passing the ID successfully from a click using useSearchParams. However, I am showing everything for all items in the database in my return. This is progress, I wasn't getting the ID previously!

I think I need to use useEffect to conditionally access id specific data but I have tried so many things at this point I've got myself tied in some knots. Any help is appreciated!

```js
    import React from "react";
    import { Link, useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";
    import { useEffect, useState } from "react";


    export default function Singleitem() {
    const [singleItem, setSingleItem] = useState([])
    const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  
    const id = searchParams.get("item");
  
    useEffect(() => {
      getItem();
    }, [id]);
  
    const getItem = async function () {
      console.log(id)
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/items?item=${id}`);
        const data = await response.json();
        setSingleItem(data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
  
    return (

      <div>
      <ul>
      {singleItem.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            {item.type}, {item.era}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
    );
    
    }
```

Event that sends the id

```js
    import React from "react";
    import { Link, useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";
    import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

    export default function Itemlist() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

    const category = searchParams.get("category");

    useEffect(() => {
     getItems();
    }, []);

    const getItems = async function () {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`/api/items? 
      category=${category}`);
      const data = await response.json();
      setItems(data);
     } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
     }
    };

    return (
    <div className="container d-flex text-uppercase fs-6 fw-semibold 
      justify-content-center">
      <ul className="justify-content-center list-unstyled pt-4">
        {items.map((item) => (
          <li className="fs-1 pt-1 mb-1 text-success" key={item.id}>
          <Link className="text-decoration-none text-success" to= 
        {`/singleitem?item=${item.id}`}>{item.type}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
       </ul>
     </div>
    );
   }
```

Comment: Welcome! To confirm, you are asserting a click results in all items' data points being rendered? Can you also include the code where `Singleitem` is being used?

Comment: It renders the id of the item (from a list), I am using that id to retrieve the data from my db. So far so good but I'm retrieving all data for all ids, I just want the data for the single item that was clicked and sent its id. Will add the code for that event.

Comment: Thanks. And more confirmations, `getItem` is logging the expected value of `id`? Can you also log `data` once defined to confirm only the data of interest is being returned, not all data?

Comment: I have made progress! Albeit it may be more annoying. It's something to do with state. The data is coming through asyncronously now. If I comment out my map of singleItem then perform click, it gives me a blank screen but console logs id twice. If I uncomment and save, the correct data shows. If I refresh from here, it breaks again.

And I might break if I can't figure this out, heh.

Comment: When it breaks, is it throwing errors? Also, as a safeguard against stale closures, can you pass `id` to your `getItem` call as an argument?